# Can Kotlin Multiplatform support Java libs?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, kotlin-multiplatform

I became aware of the new Kotlin project (https://kotlinlang.org/lp/multiplatform/). A question occurred to me.
I would like to use my Java API in my Kotlin Multiplatform. Would that work? And if not, what is the best thing to do?

Comment: Sure, you can use Java APIs in the JVM part of your multiplatform project. Did you *try* anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Kotlin Multiplatform can support many Java libraries, such as Mockito, JUnit, and Guava.
However, there are a few exceptions, like Reflection.
I recommend checking the compatibility guide for more information =) https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-compatibility-guide.html#deprecated-support-of-multiplatform-libraries-published-in-the-legacy-mode